# How did deva path pain get killed by a rasengan?

Tags: naruto

He got hit by a double meat tank and tanked tailed beast ball easily. And he's able to block sage mode taijutsu. But how did he get killed by a stupid rasengan?

Comment: Maybe there is a reason Rasengan is epitome of Shape Transformation. Remember a small imperfect Rasengan one shoted Kabuto who was an expert healer.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the wikis of [Nagato](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nagato) and [Chibaku Tensei Justu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Chibaku_Tensei)  (*Planetary Devastation*), **and while this is mere speculation**, Deva Path *couldn't* survive the Rasengan because of the prior events.

When Naruto was in his tailed beast form, Pain was retreating in order to perform the Chibaku Tensei Justu.

> To perform this technique through one of his Six Paths of Pain, Nagato needed to bring his Deva Path in close proximity to his body so that he could channel his chakra to it more effectively

While Deva Path was retreating, Nagato focused his strength and charka into Deva Path in order to survive the barrage of attacks received by Naruto.

In the aftermath, the draw back to the Chibaku Tensei Justu was that it caused severe stress to Nagato

> At low chakra levels, it placed a massive strain on his body which caused him to bleed from the mouth and nose

Because of the massive stress Nagato took, while Deva Path could still use his attractive and repulsive abilities, Nagato was not able exert enough charka in order for Deva Path to survive